# Replacing label text removes the enclosed span

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to toggle the text and icons for the collapse panel in bootstrap. The icons seems to change properly but if i try to replace the label text, the spans are removed and i only see the icons. What is wrong with this?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row bgGray text-center">
            <div id="divOptionsCI" class="col-xs-12 clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerFrequencyInflation">    
                <label id="lblMoreOptCI" class="clickable" style="height:30px;color:#FFF;">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI" style="top:3px;"></span> 
                   More options 
                  <span style="top:3px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI"></span>
               </label>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#containerFrequencyInflation').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {                        
        $(".glyphCollapseCI").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
        $("#lblMoreOptCI").text('Fewer Options');
});
$('#containerFrequencyInflation').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {        
        $(".glyphCollapseCI").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
        $("#lblMoreOptCI").text('More Options');
});
```

Comment: Try to create a minimum example with the issue, with a link to a working example on codepen (or similar site). Then you can also clean up your code example here, so that there is as little code as possible that is not related to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `<span>` is inside your `<label>`. You should change the text between the `<span>` elements, but not the `<label>` element.

Below I create a `<span>` for your text, and in the js, just change the text of that `<span>`:

```
<div class="row bgGray text-center">
    <div id="divOptionsCI" class="col-xs-12 clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerFrequencyInflation">    
        <label id="lblMoreOptCI" class="clickable" style="height:30px;color:#FFF;"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI" style="top:3px;"></span> 
            <span id="lblMoreOptCISpan">More options</span>
            <span style="top:3px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

$('#containerFrequencyInflation').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {                        
   $(".glyphCollapseCI").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
   $("#lblMoreOptCISpan").text('Fewer Options');
 });

$('#containerFrequencyInflation').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {        
  $(".glyphCollapseCI").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
  $("#lblMoreOptCISpan").text('More Options');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `text()` function replaces or overrites the selected element's content so use span content for label texts to overwrite.

```
<label id="lblMoreOptCI" class="clickable" style="height:30px;color:#FFF;">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI" style="top:3px;"></span> 
              <span class='changelabel'> More options </span>
              <span style="top:3px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphCollapseCI"></span>
           </label>
```

Js

```
$('.changelabel').text('your response text here');
```